# Display jsonb data in different columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table called stores which contains a column called id, and a column called result. The result column holds a **jsonb** that looks something like this:
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di9bL.png)

I want to display the **productname** and **dateOfSale** in 2 different columns. I am using the following but the data is displayed in a single column.

```
SELECT b.field_value AS productName, count(*) FROM
( SELECT * FROM (SELECT (jsonb_array_elements(result)::jsonb)->>'name' field_name, 
(jsonb_array_elements(result)::jsonb)->>'value' field_value, 
FROM stores WHERE store_id = '1') a
WHERE a.field_name='$.productname OR a.field_name='$dateofSale') b GROUP BY b.field_value
```

I am new to PostgreSQL.

Desired Result:

| productname | dateofsale |
| --- | --- |
| DELL MONITOR | 2021 |
| DELL MONITOR | 2020 |
| LOGITECH MOUSE | 2019 |

Comment: Can you please show us the result you want and the version of postgres you are using?

Comment: @Jeremy Hi, I am using PostgreSQL 11.5. I edited my question with the desired result. Thanks!

Comment: your example data is not valid JSON

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) not as a screen shot. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should work :

```
SELECT store_id
, jsonb_path_query_first(s.result, '$[*] ? (@.name == "$.productname").value') AS productname
, jsonb_path_query_first(s.result, '$[*] ? (@.name == "$.dateofSale").value') AS dateofsale
FROM stores AS s
WHERE store_id = '1'
```

However the structure of your json data sample is a little bit strange. With the following simple json structure instead :

```
'{"$.productname": "DELL MONITOR", "$.dateofSale": "2021"}'
'{"$.productname": "DELL MONITOR", "$.dateofSale": "2020"}'
'{"$.productname": "LOGITEC MOUSE", "$.dateofSale": "2019"}'
```

The select statement would be :

```
SELECT store_id, s.result->'$.productname' AS productname, s.result->'$.dateofSale AS dateofsale
FROM stores AS s
WHERE store_id = '1'
```